# How to uninstall crebs in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, uninstall, software-uninstall, crebs

I recently installed [crebs](http://www.obfuscatepenguin.net/crebs/) by downloading the source code and following the instructions and running setup.sh as root. I did it this way because the ppa was not working. however i have no idea how to uninstall it,I tried doing the usual uninstall method by typing: `sudo apt-get remove crebs` however i got a not found output. Please help! thanks in advance!

The output of `ls /usr/local/share/`: `applications  ca-certificates  crebs  emacs  fonts  man  sgml  xml`

Also the output of `whereis -b crebs` is `crebs: /usr/local/bin/crebs`

P.S. If you need more info please feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Can you run `dpkg -l | grep crebs` for me and edit your question with the output? That would help a lot. Also, can you run and post the output of `ls /usr/local/`?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness `dpkg -l | grep crebs ` has no output.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I'm sorry, I am a newbie, I feel like I am making a mistake, exactly how am I supposed to write this (`dpkg -l | grep crebs`) in the terminal?

Comment: Well, you opened up terminal and typed it in and pressed enter and nothing was returned? If so, that's perfectly fine, I just needed to know that. Can you post what `ls /usr/local/` returned?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I edited the question with the output

Comment: Awesome. Can you now post the output of `ls /usr/local/share/` as well as `whereis -b crebs`? I'm using the first command to try to figure out where the application was installed for sure (I have a general idea, but just want to confirm), then I'm trying to find where the application binary is located.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I have edited the question with the outputs

Comment: I take it you followed A.B.'s instructions?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source code and come up with my own uninstall instructions below.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute these commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/crebs
sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/crebs.desktop
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/crebs.1.gz
```